# Running PhantomJS script through CRON not working

Tags: cron, phantomjs

I have read related answers on StackOverflow about my question. But the problem outlined by my question seems to be different.

If I schedule a CRON job with the following command, it works perfectly fine.

```
/path/to/phantomjs -v
```

However if I replace the '-v' in the above command with the path to a script file, it does not seem to work at all.

```
/path/to/phantomjs /path/to/script.js
```

I have verified that the path to script.js is correct. I am at loss why the script does not run when the executable prints the current version fine.

Comment: Can anyone help on this issue? I don't even know how to start debugging this problem :(